# Ignore template parameter

Tags: c++

Is there a way in the code below to say that I don't care what the `V` parameter is in `void watch(event<T, _> &e)`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum events_a {
    A_1,
    A_2,
};

enum events_b {
    B_1,
    B_2,
};

template<typename T, T V>
class event {
public:
    T id(void) {
        return V;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class event_loop {
public:
    void watch(event<T, _> &e) {
    };
};

class a1 : public event<enum events_a, A_2>
{
};


int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    a1 a;

    printf("%d\n", a.id());

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is that users should be forced to subclass `event<T,V>` and be forced to give `T` and `V`.

However the subclass of `event_loop<T>`, specifically the method watch, should work with all `event<T>` regardless of their `V`.

I don't want to template just the `watch` function as I want the user to be forced to subclass `event_loop`.

---

Bonus achievement if I can somehow make sure all subclasses of `event<T>` have a unique `V`. Shooting for the stars... :D

Comment: You could provide a default type? Supposed you don't want users having to provide it.

Comment: How do you plan on *calling* `watch()` if you don't specify the exact `event` type being passed to it? The only way I know to do that is to make `watch()` itself be templated so it can deduce the additional parameter needed for each `event`, eg: `template<typename T> class event_loop { public: template<typename U> void watch(event<T, U> &e) { }; };`

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. What do you actually want to archieve ? You're asking us to fix your solution to a problem, while we can probably advice you a better solution.... If you tell us the problem

Comment: In that case, this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @JHBonarius Yeah, sounds a bit like an xy problem.

Comment: Not sure how more minimal reproducible example could be..

Comment: What I want to do is when "users" subclass event, the should be forced provide V. However I want `watch` to work for all sub-classes of `event<T>` regardless of the value of V

Comment: That's much better :) Now add that info to the question, instead of as a comment.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28b7f8498ac7005d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify a default argument for V and static assert like the way below:

```
enum events_a {
    A_1 = 1,
    A_2,
};

enum events_b {
    B_1  = 1,
    B_2,
};

template<typename T, T V = {}>
class event {
    static_assert(V != 0, "You should Define a V");
public:
    T id() {
        return V;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct event_loop {
    void watch(event<T> &e) {}
};

class a1 : public event<enum events_a, A_2> { };
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c8d9cdd6e089838)

Comment: The `static_assert` looks strange. Why are you comparing to `0`? Is that going to work always?

Comment: Hmm, would you be ok with adding your comment as a comment in the code next to the `static_assert`?

Answer (score 3):

Just create a template argument for it and ignore it.

```
template<typename T, typename Ignore>
class event_loop {
public:
    void watch(event<T, Ignore> &e) {
    };
};
```

You could also template just the function, if you want only the function to be templated

```
template<typename T>
class event_loop {
public:
    template<typename Ignore>
    void watch(event<T, Ignore> &e) {
    };
};
```

Comment: I think the watch function itself should be the one templated. Or else `Ignore` is fixed after the instance is created.

Comment: @MukeshIngham Yes, that's possibly true. I don't know the OP's use case though, but will add it as an additional point

Comment: @38489344 I upvoted this although I wonder how "_I want the user to be forced to subclass `event_loop`_" works here?